# Who, or what, is the custodian mentioned in the Mobile Home Landlord and Tenant Rights Act?

Tags: legal-terms, residential-lease, definition, illinois

According to the Illinois [Mobile Home Landlord and Tenant Rights Act (765 ILCS 745/11)](https://law.justia.com/codes/illinois/2021/chapter-765/act-765-ilcs-745/):

> Provisions of mobile home park leases. Any lease hereafter executed or currently existing between an owner and tenant in a mobile home park in this State shall also contain, or shall be made to contain, the following covenants binding the owner at all times during the term of the lease to:
>
> ...
>
> - (i) provide a custodian's office and furnish each tenant with the name, address and telephone number of the custodian and designated office.

Who, or what, is the "*custodian*"?

Answer (score 2):

A custodian is, in simple terms, a receptionist / site warden.

Their role is not expressly defined in 765 ILCS 745 but see, for example, the [Code of Ordinances Chapter 32 (Manufactured and Mobile Homes)](https://library.municode.com/il/morrison/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=COOR_CH32MAMOHO) for the city of Morrison, Illinois which identities a custodian's duties:

> Sec. 32-180. - Custodian's office required; registration duties.
>
> (a) Each mobile home park shall be provided with a custodian's office where each mobile home entering such mobile home park shall be assigned to a lot location, given a copy of the mobile home park rules, and registered according to the prescribed form...